# Create array of object in retrofit2 using put request

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to create the array of object value using put request in android retrofit2.

```
 room:[{
    roomName:"Bedroom"
 }]
```

My Model class

```
public class CreateRooms {
    @SerializedName("room")
    ArrayList<CreateRoomName> createRoomNames;

    public void setCreateRoomNames(ArrayList<CreateRoomName> createRoomNames) {
        this.createRoomNames = createRoomNames;
    }

    public class CreateRoomName{
        public CreateRoomName(String room_name) {
            this.room_name = room_name;
        }

        @SerializedName("roomName")
        String room_name;
    }

}
```

ApiInterface

```
@PUT
    Call<CreateRooms.CreateRoomName> createRooms(@Url String url, @Body ArrayList<CreateRooms> createRooms);
```

Pass values

```
Call<CreateRooms> createRoomsCall = cloudInterface.createRooms("url","string");
                            createRoomsCall.enqueue(new Callback<CreateRooms>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<CreateRooms> call, Response<CreateRooms> response) {
                                    if(response.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"res:"+response.body(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"not success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<CreateRooms> call, Throwable throwable) {

                                }
                            });
```

Can anyone guid me how to create array of object value in android retrofit2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `CreateRooms` contains `ArrayList<CreateRoomName>`,

From my understanding, you can use a single object of `CreateRooms` instead of `ArrayList<CreateRooms>`

```
@PUT
Call<CreateRooms.CreateRoomName> createRooms(@Url String url, @Body CreateRooms createRoom);
```

I hope this will help.

Edited...

```
void passValue(String... names){
    CreateRooms rooms = new CreateRooms();
    rooms.createRoomNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String name : names){
        rooms.createRoomNames.add(new CreateRooms.CreateRoomName(name));
    }

    Call<CreateRooms> createRoomsCall = cloudInterface.createRooms("url",rooms);
    createRoomsCall.enqueue(new Callback<CreateRooms>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CreateRooms> call, Response<CreateRooms> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"res:"+response.body(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"not success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CreateRooms> call, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    });
}
```

Make `CreateRoomName` as inner static class.

You have to pass room names `passValue("room name 1', "room name 2", "room name 3")`

Comment: Thanks for quick reply alex. But how to pass values?

Comment: Thanks for your answering. Here, i want to add values to existing room array. I thought of above code stuff will create new array at server side.

Comment: Then, you can pass the `roomId` of  room with updated name, so that server can find the updated name by id. Does it makes sense?

Comment: I tried your answer, it will create new array at mongodb. Here what  is roomId?

Comment: roomId - Unique identifier for the existing room. Maybe the primary key in room table.

Comment: room:[{
    roomName:"Bedroom"
 }] , roomId is room sir, but iam little bit confusing sir. How to use roomId in code.

Comment: If you call the example method the request will be like: room:[{ roomName:"room name 1" },{ roomName:"room name 2" },{ roomName:"room name 3" }]. Here, new room will be created. If you want to add value to extisting room array, you should handle in server-side.

Comment: I thought of we are passing array sir. Example method request correct.